# In-app billing - error in generated IInAppBillingService.java

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Trying to use in-app billing V3 for the first time, targeting Android 2.2 (API level 8), using Eclipse.

Created a package (in /src) called com.android.vending.billing, dropped (imported) IInAppBillingService.aidl into it. But /gen now contains build errors, eg for

```
@Override public int isBillingSupported(int apiVersion, java.lang.String packageName, java.lang.String type) throws android.os.RemoteException
```

it says "The method isBillingSupported(int, String, String) of type IInAppBillingService.Stub.Proxy must override a superclass method ... ".

It recommends I remove the @override but this is a google supplied file and I don't want to change it. What's gone wrong?

Cleaning and rebuilding doesn't help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will get this error if you are using Java 5. Java 5 has a few problems with the `@Override` annotation.

You need to make sure you jave Java 6 installed, and then you can change the version used for building by going to `Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler` and checking the `Enable project specific settings` box and changing the `Compiler compliance level:` value to `1.6`

Android Tools don't play nice with Java 7, so don't use `1.7`.